# Convert json into spacy format

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I'm new to Python ,help me how to pass json value as parameter instead of load from filename.Please check below code for reference..

```py
import json

filename = input("Enter your train data filename : ")

print(filename)


with open(filename) as train_data:

    train = json.load(train_data)

TRAIN_DATA = []
for data in train:

    ents = [tuple(entity) for entity in data['entities']]

    TRAIN_DATA.append((data['content'],{'entities':ents}))


with open('{}'.format(filename.replace('json','txt')),'w') as write:

    write.write(str(TRAIN_DATA))
```

In above code json value loaded from file ,instead of file i want to pass json value and load ....

Ex:

```py
train_data=[{"content":"what is the price of polo?","entities":[[21,25,"PrdName"]]}

with open(filename) as train_data:

    train = json.load(train_data)
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "pass json value as parameter"? Python doesn't have "JSON values", it has dictionaries, lists, strings, integers and floating-point numbers, so when you load your JSON from a file or a string, you get a dictionary of such values or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

"json value" doesn't mean anything. Json is a text format, not a data type, and what `json.loads()` do is to transform the json text to python objects - dicts, lists etc - according to the `json` syntax and what exact type makes sense in Python (json object -> dict, json array -> list etc). You can check this by yourself in your Python shell:

```
>>> import json
>>> jsonstr = '{"foo":"bar", "baaz":[1, 2, 3]}'
>>> json_data = json.loads(jsonstr)
>>> json_data
{'foo': 'bar', 'baaz': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> type(json_data)
<class 'dict'>
```

IOW, if you already have the correct Python dict, you have **nothing** else to do.